Can you arrange the positive integers so that certain numbers are relatively prime?
Can you arrange the positive integers $(1, \ 2, \ 3, \ \cdots)$ into a sequence
$$T_1, \ T_2, \ T_3, \ \cdots$$
such that the sequence contains every positive integer exactly once
AND
if $i, \ j, \ k$ are consecutive terms in the sequence then
$i$ and $j$ are relatively prime and
$i$ and $k$ are relatively prime and
$j$ and $k$ are relatively prime?
Note:  Two numbers are relatively prime if $1$ is the only positive number that is a common divisor of both numbers.

Construct a sequence by

alternately taking two primes followed by one nonprime, i.e., 2, 3, 1, 5, 7, 4, 11, 13, 6, ...

Formally,

If $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}=(2,3,5,\dots)$ is the sequence of primes and $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}=(1,4,6,\dots)$ is the sequence of nonprimes, define $T_{3n}=p_{2n}$, $T_{3n+1}=p_{2n+1}$, and $T_{3n+2}=c_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Clearly,

the sequence contains every positive integer exactly once.

Furthermore,

every three consecutive terms consists of two primes greater than one nonprime, which are pairwise coprime.


Your last point may need expanding. It is not obvious that your composite number will always be smaller than the adjacent primes. (The overall density of the primes makes it likely, but that's not a proof.)

I thought if the number at a certain place is even, then the 4 immediate surrounding numbers (2 on each side) must be odd, so odd and even numbers can't be equally densely populated like they're supposed to. Maybe I'm just dumb, but that it apparently doesn't have to be this way is wild to me.

@Nautilus Consider the sequence 1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 4, 9, 11, 6, 13, 15, 8, ...  This sequence contains all the positive odd numbers and all the positive even numbers.  Infinities can be tricky!

@fljx All evens greater than 2 are composite, which alone guarantees the primes grow faster.
